# JDBC: How to store and retrieve hashed passwords

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I'm trying to make a simple but secure login system. I've read that hashing and salting passwords gives sufficient security if you're using a good algorithm for hashing and creating a unique salt for each hash. I found this code-snippet on the OWASP website for the hashing method:

```
public static byte[] hashPassword(final char[] password, final byte[] salt, final int iterations, final int keyLength) {

    try {
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, keyLength);
        SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(spec);
        byte[] res = key.getEncoded();
        return res;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

and I'm using SecureRandom to generate the salt

```
    public static byte[] generateSalt(int length) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
      byte[] salt = new byte[length];
      random.nextBytes(salt);
      return salt;
}
```

**This is where my question comes**

I would like to store the hashed password and salt to a database using JDBC.
I'm not sure which datatype to use in the databse (varchar? blob? something else?)

I've tried storing the byte array as a varchar and reading it as a String, but when i output the result i get all question marks, so i guess that's not the way to do it.

A blob looks right, considering its storing bytes. But all the examples i find seem to use it for storing images so i was thinking there might be another approach for byte arrays? What's the way to do it?

Comment: You could convert the byte[] to a hex String

Comment: That was alot easier. Thanks!